# how to generate assimp .so in android ndk i am using assimp 3.0

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk, assimp

I am facing this error in android studio 2.2.1
Error:Shared library link file E:\path\3dmodelndk\AssimpAndroid-master\app\src\main\externals\assimp-3.0\libs\armeabi-v7a\libassimp.so does not exist for prebuilt shared library ‘my_assimp:armeabi-v7aDebugShared’

build.gradle:

```
// Assimp prebuilt shared lib
        my_assimp {
            // Inform Android Studio where header file dir for this lib
            headers.srcDir "src/main/externals/assimp-3.0/include"
            // Inform Android Studio where lib is -- each ABI should have a lib file
            binaries.withType(SharedLibraryBinary) {
                sharedLibraryFile = file("src/main/externals/assimp-3.0/libs/" +
                        "${targetPlatform.getName()}/libassimp.so")
            }
        }
```

buildForAndroid.sh:

```
//!/bin/sh

//Path to Android NDK
export ANDROID_NDK=$Android_NDK

//Points to the Android SDK
export ANDROID_SDK=$Android_SDK
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK/tools/bin

//from https://github.com/taka-no-me/android-cmake
export ANDROID_STANDALONE_TOOLCHAIN=$ANDROID_SDK/cmake/3.6.3155560  /android.toolchain.cmake

//Add additional args here as appropriate
cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=$ANDROID_STANDALONE_TOOLCHAIN \
  -DANDROID_NDK=$ANDROID_NDK \
  -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
  -DANDROID_ABI="x86" \
  -DANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL=android-9 \
  -DANDROID_FORCE_ARM_BUILD=TRUE \
  -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=install \
  ..

//This is to remove the versioned shared libs in assimp.
sed -i s/-soname,libassimp.so.3/-soname,libassimp.so/g code/CMakeFiles/assimp.dir/link.txt

//make -j4
```